# For an intersecting family of $m$ sets there are at least $2m$ sets that are contained in at least one of them

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

Let $F$ be a finite family of non-empty sets such that any two of them intersect. Consider the set $F'$ consisting of all sets that are a subset of at least one element of $F$. Prove $|F'|\geq 2|F|$.

I conjectured this yesterday but have been completely unable to prove it. I tried doing things like inclusion-exclusion on the poset of the subsets but I was not able to solve it, I also tried things similar to Dilworth's theorem.

Since this problem is so natural I think that it should have been attempted before, does anyone have any references?

Comment: What about $F':=F$? Then $\ |F'|<2\cdot|F|\ $ for every non-empty $F$. Perhaps you've meant something else.

Comment: This might be equivalent to the Union-Closed Sets conjecture.  Have you tried stretching it in that direction, perhaps using the dual of the membership relation?  Gerhard "Taking A Wild Guess Here" Paseman, 2017.04.27.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński that is impossible, because the empty set is always in $F'$ and not in $F$, besides,  $F$ is an intersecting family. I don't think that trivial counterexamples exist.

Comment: I misread or misinterpreted your statement (I suspected it). Perhaps I follow you now.

Comment: I appreciate your question (+1 :-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assume that all the sets are contained in some master set of $n$ elements. Let $G$ be the set of super sets of at least one element of $F$. We apply the Harris-Kleitman inequality:

**Lemma** (Harris-Kleitman): *For $F'$ a downward-closed and $G$ an upward-closed collection of subsets on a set with $n$ elements,* $$|F'\cap G|\leq \frac{|F'| |G| }{2^n}.$$

*Proof*. Induction on $n$. Let $G_0$ be the set of elements of $G$ that do not contain the first element, $G_1$ the set of elements that contain the first element, and so on. Then $$
\begin{aligned}
|F'\cap G|&= |F'_0 \cap G_0|+|F'_1 \cap G_1| \\
&\leq \frac{ |F'_0||G_0|}{2^{n-1}}+ \frac {|F'_1||G_1|}{2^{n-1}}\\
&= \frac{ (|F'_0|-|F'_1|) (|G_0|-|G_1|)}{2^n}+ \frac{(|F'_0|+|F'_1|)(|G_0|+|G_1|)}{2^n} \\
&\leq 0+ \frac{|F'||G|}{2^n}
\end{aligned}
$$
QED

Now by the assumption on $F$, for any element of $G$, its complement is not in $G$, so $|G|\leq 2^{n-1}$, and thus

$$|F| \leq |F' \cap G| \leq \frac{|F'||G|}{2^n} \leq \frac{|F'|}{2}$$ as desired.

Comment: Did you already know that lemma? Is it famous?

Comment: @WillSawin Is "upward-claws" supposed to be "upward-closed"? Also, would you mind if I did a small edit to improve readability?

Comment: @JoeSilverman Yes, indeed. And please make your edit. I typed this in a bit of a rush...

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I had not already seen that lemma, although I may have seen something similar. I'd be surprised if nothing like it had ever appeared in the literature before, but other than that I don't know.

Comment: @WillSawin I meant the one that you used about upward and downward closed sets. Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: I believe the Lemma is sometimes referred to as the Harris Kleitman inequality.  Probabilistically, you can view it as saying the events that a random subset belong to F' and G are negatively correlated.

Comment: @KevinP.Costello Thanks. I have added this name to the answer. I probably have seen this before, and forgotten about it.

Comment: If we take a set $X$ and an intersecting family $F$ of $2^{|X|-1}$ subsets of $X$ (which can be done in multiple ways), then equality is achieved.  Is this the only case when equality is achieved?  (Of course, the literature on intersecting families is so vast that there is zero probability that these questions have not been studied before.)

Comment: @BrendanMcKay You can also take the product of such a family with an arbitrary downward-closed family on another set. I think everything has to be of this form. Examining the proof of the Harris-Kleitman inequality, we see that if it is sharp, then the set of elements that $F'$ depends on and the set of elements that $G$ depends on must be disjoint. For the full proof to be sharp, in addition we must have $F = F' \cap G$ and $G$ is an intersecting family of half the subsets. This immediately implies that $F$ is such a product.

Comment: You can also take a sunflower with size 2 petals and a singleton center.  There may be other cases of equality. Gerhard "Is Saying It With Flowers" Paseman, 2017.04.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I believe that's the product of a downward-closed family (the petals, not including the center) with an intersecting family of maximal size (the center). Note that the center has to be one of the elements for the inequality to be sharp.

Comment: @WillSawin: I do not follow the second to last line before the "QED" mark. I do not understand why the first term has to be less than or equal to $0$.

Comment: @Bombyxmori Because $|F_0'| \geq |F_1'|$ and $|G_0| \leq |G_1|$ because $F'$ is downward-closed and $G$ is upward-closed.

Comment: @WillSawin: I see. I think you put an partial ordering by inclusion already. Thanks for the clarification.